# How to correctly transfer DOM elements across files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a function which takes in a tag name and text as input and returns all the elements made of the given tag containing the given text as output (I get an array of all the elements having the matching text).

I will be using this function across multiple functions so I thought I could save it in another file and import the function into all the other files that I may need but I am unable to transfer the element. I am using puppeteer to open the browser and get my required documents.

The code I am importing:

```
commonFunctions.js:
module.exports = {
    matchTagAndTextContents: async function matchTagAndTextContents(page, selector, text) {
        const ele = await page.evaluate((selector,text) => {
            function matchTagAndText(sel, txt) {
                var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
                return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element){
                    return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
                });
            }
            const matchedElements = matchTagAndText(selector,text);
            return matchedElements;
        },selector,text);
        return ele;
    }
}
```

Another file where I try to use the imported function:

```
foo.js:
const commonFunctions = require('./commonFunctions');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let browser = null;
browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});

(async () => {
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com");
    let elem = null; 
    await commonFunctions.matchTagAndTextContents(page,'h1','Google').then( res => {
        elem = res;
    });
    await page.evaluate((elem) => {
        elem.forEach( el => {
            el.click();
        })
    },elem);
})();
```

Here inside foo.js I keep getting el.click() is not a function, but if I implement the forEach inside the commonFunctions.js like:

```
matchedElements.forEach( el => {
    el.click();
});
```

It works and the element gets clicked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thats beacause elem is null in your execution and res its assigned to elem in the evaluated scope.

try changing

```
    let elem = null; 
await commonFunctions.matchTagAndTextContents(page,'h1','Google').then( res => {
    elem = res;
});
await page.evaluate((elem) => {
    elem.forEach( el => {
        el.click();
    })
},elem);
```

whith

```
var elem = null; 
elem = await commonFunctions.matchTagAndTextContents(page,'h1','Google');
await page.evaluate((elem) => {
    elem.forEach( el => {
        el.click();
    })
},elem);
```

Comment: This didn't solve the issue, I am sill getting .click not a function error.